# Windows Phone Data-bound TextBox Automatically Updates Souce To a Rounded Value

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone page that displays information about a geographical point including latitude, longitude and distance from the previous point.

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Points}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Lat, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Lon, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Distance, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

It is bound to the view model that also recalculates coordinates and issues PropertyChanged event for all members.

```
    public double Distance
    {
        get { return _distance; }
        set 
        {
            _distance = value;
            _lat = 12.34567890123456;
            _lon = 34.567890123456;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(String.Empty);
        }
    }
    private double _distance;

    public double Lon
    {
        get { return _lon; }
        set { 
            _lon = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(String.Empty); 
        }
    }
    private double _lon;

    public double Lat
    {
        get { return _lat; }
        set 
        { 
            _lat = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(String.Empty); 
        }
    }
    private double _lat;
```

I also have a simple function that updates this property for test purposes.

```
    private void AppButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GeoPoint currentPoint = ViewModel.Points.View.CurrentItem as GeoPoint;
        currentPoint.Distance= 1000;
    }
```

So what happens is when I click the button, first the "set" for Distance is called, but nanoseconds after the "set" for Lat and Lon are also called from an external code and with rounded value (values I can actually see in the controls). Specifically in a "set" for Lon value that comes as a parameter is 34.5679. This makes my application to update the database with rounded (displayed) values instead of actual values.

If I set the bidding mode to OneWay for Lat and Lon controls, the behavior is as expected. According to MSDN documentation, TwoWay binding to a TextBox updates the source by default when the focus is lost. In my example Lat and Lon never got focus.

What is the reason of this behavior? Is there a way to configure TextBox not to update the bound value when it's not actually changed by the user?

UPDATE:
I can reproduce this behavior even easier by calling

```
currentPoint.Distance = 123.456789123;
```

In this case the "set" for Distance is called twice - first with value==123.456789123, and 2nd time with value==123.457.

UPDATE2:
Here is calls stack for the first call:

```
>   GeoPoints.exe!GeoPoints.DataModel.GeoPoint.Distance.set(double value) Line 144  C#
GeoPoints.exe!GeoPoints.PointPage.AppButtonCancel_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 121  C#
```

And for the second call:

```
>   GeoPoints.exe!GeoPoints.DataModel.GeoPoint.Distance.set(double value) Line 144  C#
[Native to Managed Transition]  
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.CustomPropertyImpl.InvokeInternal(object target, object[] args, bool getValue)    Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.CustomPropertyImpl.SetValue(object target, object value)  Unknown
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, I think, but it is definitely a problem to call NotifyPropertyChanged using String.Empty. You should use the name of the property that has changed as a parameter.

Comment: Also, if you update the fields instead of the properties of the view model, the UI will never get notified about the changes either.

Comment: Unfortunately the code you have provided is not enough to reproduce the behavior you describe. It will be necessary to provide additional context. Can you provide the StackTrace when the second call that rounds the values is made? Make sure to unselect "Show only user code" to see what is making the calls.

Comment: Thanks, @Murven! I'm using String.Empty because changing one parameters of the model updates most of the other parameters, and this is also the reason I'm updating fields instead of properties, which also enables me to call NotifyProperyChange just once.

Comment: @Murven, I've also updated the original post with call stack from both calls, and changing to 'NotifyPropertyChanged("Distance")' does not change the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fully fix the issue using the following converter:

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

public class DoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var doubleNumber = (double)value;
        return doubleNumber.ToString("0.00#################");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var stringValue = (string)value;
        return double.Parse(stringValue);
    }
}
```

You can use it in your XAML like this:

```
<Page
x:Class="PhoneAnswer001.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:PhoneAnswer001"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.Resources>
    <local:DoubleConverter x:Key="DoubleConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Points}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Latitude, Converter={StaticResource DoubleConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" InputScope="NumberFullWidth"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Longitude, Converter={StaticResource DoubleConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" InputScope="NumberFullWidth" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Distance, Converter={StaticResource DoubleConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" InputScope="NumberFullWidth" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Command="{Binding Path=CancelCommand}"/>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

You can edit the format in the converter to fit your needs or you can even add it as a parameter for the converter.

I hope this is more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a nice workaround but not a complete solution because the setter would need to do heavy calculations more then once and some accuracy of double is still lost anyway. I think I will go with handling LostFocus event.

Comment: I have updated the answer, I was able to fix it using a converter.

Comment: Also works! Thanks a lot! However it does not solve the basic problem that the TextBox starts data update when user actually did not entered anything in the TextBox. The solution helps to minimize an effect of this, but does not avoid unnecessary (and in my case heavy) updates.